# "Notice (8): Undefined index: " cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am building a pdf conversion utility for my user.
I am working in `CakePhp` and my controller is receiving  Ajax call. 
Why i am getting **Notice:8** error

**Controller:**

```
public function convertToPdf() {
            $this->autoRender = false;
            $pdf = new WkHtmlToPdf;
            //$this->RequestHandler->respondAs('json');
            // echo $convertData = json_encode($inputVal);

            if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
                $pdfName = uniqid();
                if ($_FILES['conversionSourceFile']) {
                    echo "File";
                    $pdf->addPage($_FILES['conversionSourceFile']['tmp_name']);
                } elseif ($_POST['conversionSourceUrl']) {
                    echo "Url";
                    $pdf->addPage($_POST['conversionSourceUrl']);
                } elseif ($_POST['conversionSourceHtml']) {
                    echo "Html";
                    $pdf->addPage('<html>' . $_POST['conversionSourceHtml'] . '</html>');
                }

                $saveToPath = 'upload/' . $pdfName . '.pdf';
                if ($pdf->saveAs($saveToPath)) {
                    echo 'upload/' . $pdfName . '.pdf';
                }
            }
        }
```

**Error:**
    Notice (8): Undefined index: conversionSourceFile [APP/Controller/PdfsController.php, line 42]
    Code Context

```
if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
            $pdfName = uniqid();
            if ($_FILES['conversionSourceFile']) {

PdfsController::convertToPdf() - APP/Controller/PdfsController.php, line 42
ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs() - [internal], line ??
Controller::invokeAction() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 486
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 187
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 162
[main] - APP/webroot/index.php, line 109
```

Comment: Why you not check to `isset($_FILES['conversionSourceFile'])` within if condition and then do more stuff?

Comment: @hallaji : please make your comment as ans. i need to give you +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply check to `isset` $_FILES superglobal variable to prevent notice when not set.

```
if (isset($_FILES['conversionSourceFile'])) {
    // Do more stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To avoid `notice` in your code you have to use `isset()` OR `!empty()`.

Using `isset()` and `!empty()` you can check whether variable is set and does not have an empty value.

e.g,

```
if (isset($_FILES['conversionSourceFile'])) {
    // your code
}
```

OR

```
if (!empty($_FILES['conversionSourceFile'])) {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: You need to check for both in this situation, only checking for `empty` will give an undefined index error incase it isn't set..

Comment: Or suppress notices/warnings using `@` e.g.: `if (@$_FILES['conversionSourceFile']) { // stuff here }`

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the first condition, with an "isset" or "!empty ()", like:

```
if(isset($_FILES['conversionSourceFile'])){...}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved the error "Notice (8): Undefined index" changing the order var $ uses.

before:

```
class GastosController extends AppController {  
    var $uses = array('Comprobante','Gasto','TipoGasto');
```

...
...
..

After:

```
class GastosController extends AppController {  
    var $uses = array('Gasto','Comprobante','TipoGasto');
```

..
..
..

Put the name that corresponds to the class (Gasto) first.